# How to define regex for portia

Tags: portia

I'm trying to build a regex so i can enter this in Portia as a link follow rule

the url structure in question is : https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/5826/Stages/12496/TeamStatistics/England-Premier-League-2015-2016

All the number parts are variable.. + the last bit of the url

is there a way to clearly define this in link following rules?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct structure using regex could be:

```
(https:\/\/www\.whoscored\.com\/Regions\/252\/Tournaments\/2\/Seasons\/5826\/Stages\/12496\/TeamStatistics\/England-Premier-League-2015-2016)+
```